# find nearest match string to array php

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I have a string value held in a var, I want to compare it against a array and print the array number that is the nearest match whilst being case sensitive.

so the question is how do I find the nearest match within my array to my var `$bio` in this case it would be **4**

I have seen pregmatch but am unsure on how to use it in this case.

**Code I have**

```
<?php
$bio= "Tom, male, spain";

$list= array(
    1 => array("Tom", "male", "UK"),
    8 => array("bob", "Male", "spain"),
    4 => array("Tom", "male", "spain"),
    9 => array("sam", "femail", "United States")
);

function best_match($bio, $list)

{

}
```

I was thinking something like thinking

```
$matches  = preg_grep ($bio, $list);

print_r ($matches);
```

Comment: *nearest match* based on what ?

Comment: good point ill update question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way using [array_intersect:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$bio= "Tom, male, spain";

$list= array(
    1 => array("Tom", "male", "UK"),
    8 => array("bob", "Male", "spain"),
    4 => array("Tom", "male", "spain"),
    9 => array("sam", "femail", "United States")
);

function best_match($bio, $list) {
    $arrbio = explode(', ', $bio);
    $max = 0;
    $ind = 0;
    foreach($list as $k => $v) {
        $inter = array_intersect($arrbio, $v);
        if (count($inter) > $max) {
            $max = count($inter);
            $ind = $k;
        }
    }
    return [$ind, $max];
}
list($index, $score) = best_match($bio, $list);
echo "Best match is at index: $index with score: $score\n";
```

**Output:**

```
Best match is at index: 4 with score: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a job for [similar text](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php), i.e:

```
$bio= "Tom, male, spain";

$list = array(
    1 => array("Tom", "male", "UK"),
    8 => array("bob", "Male", "spain"),
    4 => array("Tom", "male", "spain"),
    9 => array("sam", "femail", "United States")
);

$percent_old = 0;
foreach ($list as  $key => $value ) # loop the arrays
{
    $text = implode(", ", $value); # implode the array to get a string similar to $bio
    similar_text($bio, $text, $percent); # get a percentage of similar text

    if ($percent > $percent_old) # check if the current value of $percent is > to the old one
    {
        $percent_old = $percent; # assign $percent to $percent_old
        $final_result = $key; # assign $key to $final_result
    }
}

print $final_result;
# 4
```

[PHP Demo](https://ideone.com/skaidD)

Comment: this looks promising, thanks ill try and accept answer soon